# Missing named ranges when copying from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

Most named ranges are copying correctly, but some are not.  Looking in Name Manager of the copied file, the ranges which don't copy correctly still ReferTo the source file, not the copy.  The ones which do copy correctly point to the local copy as they should.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim TemplateTemplate As Worksheet, SummaryTemplate As Worksheet
    Dim datafile As Workbook

    With ActiveWorkbook
        Set TemplateTemplate = .Sheets("Template")
        Set SummaryTemplate = .Sheets("Summary")
    End With

' Open up a new workbook
`    Set datafile = Workbooks.Add

`' Copy worksheets to new "datafile"
    SummaryTemplate.Copy After:=datafile.Sheets(datafile.Sheets.Count)  ' All named ranges copied
    TemplateTemplate.Copy After:=datafile.Sheets(datafile.Sheets.Count) ' Missing 4 named ranges
    TemplateTemplate.Copy After:=datafile.Sheets(datafile.Sheets.Count) ' Missing 4 named ranges
End Sub
```

No error messages, but 4 of the 10 named ranges from TemplateTemplate are not copying correctly.  If I comment out the SummaryTemplate copy, then all ranges from TemplateTemplate copy over.  If I change the order, i.e. TemplateTemplate copied before SummaryTemplate, then all ranges copy over correctly.  Looking at Name Manager, there's nothing unique about the definition of the 4 ranges in the source file.  Looking at Name Manager for the copies, the incorrect copies ReferTo the source file, instead of to the copy ("datafile") file.

Comment: Verify the scope of the names that work, compare to the scope of the names that fail

Comment: Scope the same on all names

Comment: TBH I'd probably just wipe the `Names` collection clean on the new book/sheets, and re-create them all. Copying names has a tendency to annoyingly carry paths/filenames of the old file into the new one, and then you open the workbook and Excel complains about missing linked files..

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I'll add the names in VBA.  Interestingly enough, though ranges named in a worksheet appear in the Names window, they do not appear in the VBA Names collection, so they cannot be deleted in VBA.  Ranges defined using VBA do get added to the names collection.

Comment: *Ranges defined using VBA do get added to the names collection.* - that is wrong. Make sure you qualify the `Names` collection with a `Workbook` object to scope them to that workbook. If you're in a worksheet module's code-behind, `Names` implicitly refers to `Me.Names` and makes the names worksheet-scoped.